# Actionscript 3; error 1086

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Currently coding a game in Actionscript 3, and the following function keeps spitting out this error;

```
function checkAnswer(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
    var input:String(this.userInput.text).toLowerCase();
    var currentLetter:int;
    var currentWord = currentFruit;
    while (currentLetter < input.length){ 
    if (this.currentWord.charAt(currentLetter) == input.charAt(currentLetter)){
                   trace("correct");
                } else {
                    trace("incorrect");
                };
           currentLetter++;
        }

};
```

And the error;

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 81  1086: Syntax error: expecting semicolon before leftparen.
```

I have no idea why it is doing this. Does anyone have any clue? Can anyone help?

Comment: Probably just change `var input:String(this.userInput.text).toLowerCase();` to `var input:String = (this.userInput.text).toLowerCase();` solves this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
 var input:String(this.userInput.text).toLowerCase();
```

to

```
var input:String = this.userInput.text.toLowerCase();
```